# Hiding an element until a selection is made

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, razor

Within a form in a Razor View, I have the following elements:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Published"></label><span style="color:red">*</span>
     <select asp-for="Published"
             asp-items="Model.PublishList"
             class="form-control" id="pub" onchange="hideRegen()" ></select>
     <span asp-validation-for="Published" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="regen" hidden>
     <label asp-for="Regenerate"></label><span style="color:red">*</span>
     <select asp-for="Regenerate"
             asp-items="Model.Regenerates"
             class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
     <span asp-validation-for="Regenerate" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

And in the script element, I have the following function:

```
<script>
    (function hideRegen() {
        var pub = document.getElementById("pub");
        var regen = document.getElementById("regen");
        if (pub.options[pub.selectedIndex].text == "No") {
            regen.show();
        }
        this.form.submit();
    });
</script>
```

Both **select** elements draw items from a list containing "Yes," "No," and "". The second **div** should be hidden until the first element is changed to "No."

When I test this code in IIS, nothing happens. When I tried it in JSFiddle, I get an error ["Uncaught ReferenceError: hideRegen is not defined."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)

I've checked other questions here for that error and can't figure out why it's occurring. The scope should be correct, since the function is at the top level of the script. But I'm *very* new to JS and don't know what I might be missing here. Any help correcting the error or accomplishing hiding the second element in another way is much appreciated.

Comment: could you add the link of the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Lfmx1Gd5cD the HTML is a bit different because I don't have the asp data to pull from, but I think it should be operating the same way.

Comment: Could you check this https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/OJyZXLx seems like the in JSFiddle the ID reference was not correct & the only change I did was used removeAttribute('hidden')

Comment: Hmm, which ID reference was changed? I don't see it. I tried using the removeAttribute('hidden') function instead of the show(), but there was no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have it working correctly. The function posted in the question wasn't working because of an extra pair of parentheses I added by mistake (I copied from an example I didn't fully understand, mea culpa.)

I used the following JS:

```
function showRegen() {
        var pub = document.getElementById("pub");
        var regen = document.getElementById("regen");
        if (pub.options[pub.selectedIndex].text == "No") {
            regen.removeAttribute('hidden');
        }
};
window.addEventListener('load', showRegen());
form.addEventListener('submit', showRegen());
```

Then changed the **onchange** attribute of the first element to "this.form.submit()." (This works best for my code because there is logic in the controller that implements warning text based on the values of these two elements.)

Thanks @Aarif and @Neha Sharma for looking at it.